# Why connection token passed in the URL in Signal R?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I got a website to handle all security issues raised by a software during Pen Testing. Please refer to the following screen shot:

[image]

jquery.signalR-2.4.1 is being used in the project (ASP.NET MVC). I need to give explanation to the security team about the use of above URL, why it is showing under a GET request. Is there any threat for the application? If yes how to remove the connection string from the query string inside the URL? If it's an inbuilt process or method what's the exact use?

Comment: If you are using https it is not an actual security issue. The only problem with it if you have request logging enabled on server side server admins can reach these tokens.

Comment: Any explanation that I can provide to my security team?

Comment: It is a security issue to pass sensitive params via GET. Tokens allowing to setup authetnicated context should not be sent via URL params. One thing is logging GET requests on the server, second thing is that in various corporate envs there can be is a corporate proxy inspecting HTTPS which can log it as well. Then you can have entries in browser's history with this param saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a connection token, not a session/security token. This is documented in Microsoft's SignalR [security section of the documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security#connectiontoken). I would refer your security team to this information as they are not aware of the difference here and how it is used. Especially the bolded portion below:

Here it is in case the link changes -

SignalR's connection token isn't an authentication token. It is used to confirm that the user making this request is the same one that created the connection. The connection token is necessary because ASP.NET SignalR allows connections to move between servers. The token associates the connection with a particular user but doesn't assert the identity of the user making the request. For a SignalR request to be properly authenticated, it must have some other token that asserts the identity of the user, such as a cookie or bearer token. However, the connection token itself makes no claim that the request was made by that user, only that the connection ID contained within the token is associated with that user.

Since the connection token provides no authentication claim of its own, it isn't considered a "session" or "authentication" token. **Taking a given user's connection token and replaying it in a request authenticated as a different user (or an unauthenticated request) will fail, because the user identity of the request and the identity stored in the token won't match.**

Comment: Is this an internal process of SignalR passing connection token within query string? I mean can we hide this by any chance?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I've never put much thought into given the documentation around what it is and how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

In SignalR there are two types of tokens. The one in the screenshot seems to be a connection and most probably the pentest team mixed the screenshots as this is some low-level issue. The real issue is that indeed SignalR is passing `access_token` via the HTTP GET URL parameter:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bearer-token-authentication

and it is stated in the documentation when Bearer token for authentication is used. There seems to also be a note added that it is recognised as a a potential security risk and more details can be found:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/security?view=aspnetcore-7.0

However to be frank the documentation is wrong. Authorization header is more secure than the GET URL parameter. Due to the fact that URLs can be logged in various places like:

- servers access logs (for various reasons mainly monitoring but also WAF)
- potentially corporate proxies when employee's laptop got corporate certificate installed, so their traffic can be monitored
- in browser's history which in case of a local compromise of the machine allows to extract the token form the history (however in this case it's not very likely to save signalr URL in the history as the user does not type it in or copy-paste it in most cases, but technically it is possible)

To sum up unfortunately it seems the issue has no proper systemic solution and some non-standard solution should be implemented which I guess in most cases will boil down to skipping it justified by a business accepted risk.